# VB6 ADO recordset fieldname case sensitivity depends on Windows language settings

Tags: ms-access, vb6, field, case-sensitive

I have an ado recordset connected to an access database. I have a SELECT * Query. I access the fields as:

```
rs!ROMRightMinX

rs!ROMRightMaxX

rs!ROMRightMinY

rs!ROMRightMaxY
```

When I switch Windows to Hungarian, the nY combination in rs!ROMRightMinY becomes case sensitive. Meaning

```
rs!ROMRightMinY      Displays value

rs!ROMRightMInY      Displays value

rs!ROMRigHTMinY      Displays value

rs!ROMRightMiny      Field not found

rs!ROMRightMiNy      Field not found

rs!ROMRightMiNY      Field not found
```

The other fields work correctly. Similarly `rs!ROMLeftMinY` has the same issue. I've renamed the field to `rs!ROMRightMiYY` and it is no longer case sensitive.

All fields work correctly in other Windows languages.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Case-sensitivity in table and field names varies between database systems. The SQL92 spec says unquoted identifiers should be case-insensitive. But, quoted identifiers should be case-sensitive.

If you can't control the case of the field names in the underlying record source, change your SELECT query to something like this:

```
SELECT ROMRightMinX AS [ROMRightMinX], ROMRightMaxX AS [ROMRightMaxX], 
    ROMRightMinY AS [ROMRightMinY], ROMRightMaxY AS [ROMRightMaxY] ...
```

(Quoting may vary according to system, I use [] here)

This way, the underlying column gets a case-insensitive match, but the returned columns are case-sensitive, so they should match your code in all locales.

Comment: But that doesn't explain why the nY at the end of ROMRightMinY and ROMLeftMinY are case sensitive and the other characters in these field names and the nY in the other field names is not. I can edit the field name at a breakpoint and when I hover the mouse over it, it either shows the value or "Field not found" as I edit the case of the nY.

Comment: Yes, I didn't try to explain that. I think that is out of your control. I was merely showing you a way to properly case the column names so your code works regardless of the locale setting.

Comment: See my answer, it might be a special case for the Hungarian digraph `NY`.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it is because `NY` in Hungarian is a [digraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraph_(orthography)). It corresponds with the behaviour you are describing. `Ny`, `ny` and `NY` are understood as one letter (the palatal nasal [ɲ]). `NX` is not a digraph in Hungarian so this works as you would expect.

Just for fun, try it with other Hungarian digraphs: `cs`, `zs`, `gy`, `ly`, `ny`, `ty`, `dz`, `sz`, and with the trigraph `dzs`.